# Angular Material "Platform" module fails to detect Edge browser

Tags: angular, angular-material

I added the [Platform](https://material.angular.io/cdk/platform) module to my project, but it fails to detect Edge browsers (Material V12.2.7, Windows 10, Edge V94).

I created [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-afzrrv) that tests the issue and prints the `Platform` output, and strangely enough, when I open the StackBlitz from an Edge browser, it fails to detect it.

Does anyone else have this issue or am I doing something wrong?

```
import { Platform } from '@angular/cdk/platform';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class AppComponent {

    isEdge: boolean;

    constructor(private platformService: Platform) {
        this.isEdge = this.platformService.EDGE; // always false!
    }
}
```

**Testing the StackBlitz from Edge browser:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this link:

https://www.decodedfrontend.io/detect-browser-and-os-with-angular-cdk-platform-module/

The newer Edge browsers use also the Blink Engine. So thats why you don't see Edge on true

Comment: Thanks. You'd think that a framework of this scale would already fix it..